# how to generate unique ID character using letters a-z

Tags: javascript, math, random

Here is a little challenge, I hope it will be useful for others too.

Task is to obtain an ID character from alphabets of english language. a-to-z

My solution currently allows ID (words) of 26 diff length (max possible). with 90 possible words.

I know this can be increased if we pick random characters after single character IDs are obtained (done with.) (But) I am finding it hard to figure out how to manage NOT hitting a combination already found (ID has to be unique). As we see it takes a long time if it starts finding the same combinations over and over. this probability increases as we obtain more and more ID-combinations.

Here is my code and fiddle to test and check:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rp_fiddle/nanu1hr9/)

code:

html

```
<p>
  start
</p>
```

jquery:

```
 function addto(t) {
    $("p").append("<b>" + t + "</b>");
  }

global_ID_array = [];
lowerAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var myIDlength = 1;
    function getIDChar (){
        do {
            var myIDchar = lowerAlpha.substr(0, myIDlength);
            lowerAlpha = lowerAlpha.replace(myIDchar,'');
            if (lowerAlpha.length < myIDlength){
                lowerAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";      //reset
                myIDlength++;
      }
        } while (global_ID_array.indexOf(myIDchar) > -1)
        global_ID_array.push(myIDchar);
        addto(myIDlength+':'+global_ID_array.length+',');
    }

  do{
  getIDChar();
  }while (myIDlength < 26);
  addto('<br \>myIDlength='+myIDlength);
  addto('<br \>global_ID_array last val='+global_ID_array[global_ID_array.length-1]+'<p>');
```

Comment: Random numbers can be most possibly generated as random but after certain occurrence of the random numbers or within the phase of generating random numbers they can be repeated same. That is why these are termed pseudo random numbers. These are not naturally random.

Comment: If you generate 26 characters, the chance of getting the same one twice is something like 1 in 6e36.

Comment: Don't remove the character you used. There's no need to prevent duplicate characters in the unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

To get started, instead of thinking about the IDs in terms of letters, think about it in terms of *numbers*.

Since there are 26 possible characters, each character can be considered as a digit of a base-26 numeric system, with `a == 0`, and `z == 25`. The problem now boils down to generating a **number** and *converting* it to base-26 using the alphabets as digits. Since the ID length is 26 characters, we can generate up to `26^26` unique IDs.

Now, to make sure that the ID generated is unique (up to `26^26` generated IDs), we need to find a way to generate a unique number every time. The simplest way to do this is to initialize a counter at 0 and use it to generate the ID. Every time an ID is done generating, increment the counter. Of course, this is a very deterministic generation algorithm, but you could use a seeded random number generator that guarantees the uniqueness of random numbers generated in a range.

The algorithm may look as follows:

```
n = random(0, 26^26 - 1)

id = "a" * 26
// chars[i] is the character representing the base-26 digit i; 
// you may change/shuffle the list as you please
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'y', 'z']

for i in 0..26 {
    // Get the character corresponding to the next base-26 digit of n (n % 26)
    id[26 - i] = chars[n % 26]
    n /= 26
}
```